# Windows 10 Home file permissions

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I'm attempting to set up a laptop for my wife with Windows 10 home. I have traditionally used c:\local for some utilities, but am having trouble now setting permissions so that I can even copy things into it.

I have an account for each of us, I make them both administrator accounts. I have an executable on a network drive I'm trying to copy into c:\local. When I copy (using File Explorer) and then attempt to paste, Windows says I need to provide administrator privilege; I click to grant that privilege for the copy, and it disappears briefly and then appears again. It will not copy the file.

I went into the security permissions on c:\local and changed ownership to my wife's account, and restarted. Then it let me copy the file. I created a shortcut for it to put on the taskbar and clicked on the shortcut - Windows told me the file had been deleted or moved -- sure enough, checked c:\local and the file is gone.

Tried to copy it again, got the "must grant administrator" runaround.

What is going on here? It's as if the permissions were all right for a short time after reboot, but then not only got changed, but eliminated files copied in during the short period between reboot starting and the change.

I suppose I should mention OneDrive, which I don't know much about -- it seems to be Micro$oft's attempt to get access to all my files with my permission, and I don't want anything to do with it. Both these user accounts are local; I have never set up a "Microsoft Account". I have read other posts about disabling it, but they all start with "open OneDrive and go to settings", and to get past the first screen in the OneDrive program I have to give it my email address. So I haven't.

I suppose I should also mention that, ideally, someone logged into either account would be able to copy things into the folder freely. There are things in there that I probably put in under my account; I'm currently on her account trying to get things set up, and would rather not have to switch back and forth just to copy files. I don't understand why both adminstrator accounts cannot do that.

Comment: Based upon my previous experience, trying to utilize a file or folder that you create at the root of the `C:` partition can lead to permissions issues like the ones you described. Under the same circumstances, I would probably use the `C:\Users\Public\Downloads` folder for what you are trying to do. It will be readily available to both of you, and you shouldn't encounter any UAC or permissions problems. You can easily create a shortcut to that folder and also pin it to the `Quick access` list within File Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the tip, but it doesn't make any sense to put these local utilities under "Downloads". The extent to which the names of folders reflect their actual contents is most of what we have going for us when we're looking through a disk for things. I don't want to make it unnatural that way, and putting a link to it somewhere is just a band-aid.

Comment: Needless to say, it's your call.  Hopefully, someone else will chime-in with an idea that suits your needs.

Comment: Name both accounts the same and use the same passwords for both source and destination computers (i.e. username: user, password: test). Make your copy.

Comment: Somewhere we've missed communications -- these are two accounts on the same machine, one for her and one for me. There aren't two computers involved here, though the files I am trying to copy started out on a different machine and got put on a network drive to transfer. And the question is really "How do I set permissions to do this", not "How do I transfer files from one machine to another?". But thanks anyway.